# Neo4J Cypher data type conversion

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a property `quantity` on our `Product`-nodes and am looking to do a cypher query that gives me all nodes with `quantity = 20` ... problem is that quantity is stored as a string in neo4j. Is there a way to cast the property to integer in the cypher query?

```
// This fails to find the required nodes
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE p.quantity = 20;

// This finds them
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE p.quantity = "20";

// I would like to do this
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE INT(p.quantity) = 20;
```

*PS: this is a really simplified usecase, we don't really have products and quantities but are just faced with existing neo4j data that has integer values stored as strings, and we would like to do some matches on these strings*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it the other way round.

```
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE p.quantity = str(20) RETURN p;
```

should also work with params.

```
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE p.quantity = str({quantity}) RETURN p;
```

or even with inline property matches

```
MATCH (p:Product {quantity : str({quantity})}) RETURN p;
```

Comment: Still no way to convert to integer?

Comment: Ah, here it is: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-toint

Comment: Looks like `str` may have been renamed to `toString`, see the [relevant current (3.x) documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#functions-tostring).

Answer (score 9):

```
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE toInt(p.quantity) = 20;
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `toInt` is the needed function for me

Comment: just as information: toInt is deprecated, please use toInteger()

Answer (score 0):

I too have been faced with that problem earlier. As far as I found out, it was not possible to do that conversion directly in cypher. I used a small Java script (using the standard Java API) to change the data types of the stored values. This is a couple of months ago though, so it might have changed with the 2.0 version.

Comment: Yes, i've seen the google groups discussion but was hoping something had changed in neo4j 2.0 ... i haven't found anything in the documentation tho.

Answer (score 0):

**toInteger** worked for me.

```
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE toInteger(p.quantity) = 20;
```

I am on neo4j version Version:  5.6.0